# Why do they make out that the Scavs run on all fours?

Tags: oblivion

No matter how many times I watch Oblivion, I am intrigued as to why they make out the Scav's , which are human to look like they run on all fours.

The below footage at 2:46 shows the scav's running away and it looks like a four legged animal.

This is a still of that scene,

[image]

I know that they probably did this to mislead the audience, but this make it unbelievable. Why would they do this?

Comment: The Scavs were trying not to look human. Mind you, given Jack Harper had such trouble getting the machine he fixed to not kill a dog, I doubt its value for such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They aren't running away on four legs, they're running away on two legs and have stumbled. The image is then frozen at the moment they fell, as you say, to mislead Jack/Vicka/The audience.

This poor unfortunate manages to take precisely two steps before falling down.

[image]

---

Upright

[image]

Running and stumbling

[image]

Freeze-frame of someone in the process of falling over

[image]

Comment: Any way you look at it, they are made out to look like they are running on all fours, the first few steps are on all fours. They are not tripping.

Comment: @KyloRen - When people run away from an unexpected enemy, they often stumble. I'm not sure what answer would satisfy you at this point.

Comment: Come on, watch the footage again, they show something that looks like a cheetah running away from the explosion.

Comment: @KyloRen - No, they really don't. You're looking at less than half a second of footage of someone stumble-running from an explosion. They fall over and the footage stops. If you stop the video above at 0:39, it looks almost identical

Comment: The time means nothing. You say they are tripping , but the footage shows a creature moving at least 10 meters or 30 feet away from the explosion taking 3 leaps. That my friend is not a trip.

Comment: @KyloRen - The time means *everything*! What you're looking at is a tiny snippet. You don't see them move more than a few feet as they fall forwards and you certainly don't see them leaping like a cheetah.

Comment: Watch again, the scav takes 3 big leaps, that is not what a human looks like tripping.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer and up-vote, due to the effort and clarity of the slow-mo work. I still believe that there was mis-leading video work to make the scavs look like they were not human. I guess that is part of the movie and generates suspense.